# Linq to SQL : want to fetch record from 100 to 200 without knowing exact Id

Tags: linq

Actually My problem is , in one of my query I can only fetch 200 records from the collection at one time so my query is once if i take 200 records and for next time I need to fetch the top record i.e. 201 to 400. so any direct function available in linq for it.

Comment: Look at `skip` and `take` but you need to order your records in a predictable way.

Comment: You're asking about paging. There are a *lot* of duplicate questions that explain you need to order the results first, then use `Skip()` and `Take()` to get the pages. Rows have no inherent order which means you *have* to impose an order with `ORDER BY` to begin with. After that, the ORM provider will translate eg `Skip(100).Take(100)` to the equivalent paging query for your database. For example, for supported versions of SQL Server `OrderBy(row=>row.Id).Skip(100).Take(100)`, becomes `ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 100 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;`

Comment: BTW you didn't explain which ORM you use. LINQ is a generic query language. Linq to SQL was essentially a demo project introduced to showcase LINQ back in 2008. Are you using EF? EF Core? Which version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would suggest that is unfair to LINQ to SQL. I would say LINQ to SQL is the only full implementation of server translated LINQ ever made available by Microsoft.

Comment: @NetMage it was definitely not full (it used client-side evaluation, didn't ). It wasn't meant to be that though. That's not an opinion, that's what MS people explained even back then. That's why it wasn't developed any further, why EF came about. When people ask about LINQ to SQL, typically they mean LINQ to EF. So what is *this* question about?

Comment: @NetMage [this MS blog is a lot harsher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/the-origin-of-linq-to-sql) explaining L2S wasn't actually supposed to exist. It was a remnant of Vista's WinFS `That’s when we realized we had no choice. If LINQ was to succeed it needed some legs to stand on. The ‘mock’ ORM I was building was shaping up to be a pretty good contender`and `; we just never thought it was actually going to be a shipping product. It was simply meant to act as a stand-in for products that now no longer existed.` That's what they said at major conferences like Teched too